# How to avoid overplotting with text_layer?

Tags: r, ggvis

I have a chart where the `layer_text` elements overplot:

```
data.frame(label=c("First", "Second","First","Second"), x=c(100,100,20,20),y=c(100,100,20,20)) %>% 
  ggvis(~x,~y) %>% 
  layer_text(text:=~label)
```

I would like to offset the text to make it readable. I was thinking about tweaking the `y` values when the are `==`, but the chart needs to go in a shiny app and I might end up having more than 2 overlapping text. That's why I wondered if there is any package/attribute that can provide a more stable solution.

The solution should look something like this:

```
data.frame(label=c("First", "Second","First","Second"),    x=c(100,100,20,20),y=c(100,98,20,18)) %>% 
  ggvis(~x,~y) %>% 
  layer_text(text:=~label)
```

Answer (score 0):

Label placement is a notoriously tricky problem. `ggrepel` implements a nice algorithmic solution, but it's not available for `ggvis`, only `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(magrittr)

data.frame(label=c("First", "Second","First","Second"), 
           x=c(100,100,20,20),
           y=c(100,100,20,20)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y,label=label)) +
  geom_text_repel() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]